# Case createdon is being populated by the related Accounts overriddencreatedon date? - Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

When users are creating cases for an account, the cases created have a createdon date that matches the related accounts overriddencreatedon field?

Has anyone ever seen this behavior or have a solution to this problem?

I can band-aid the issue by removing the related accounts overriddencreatedon value but I would like to understand why this is happening.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you don’t have any plugin which was developed for some data migration still enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Posting in case anyone else experiences similar issues. The issue was caused by data mappings that were defined under an entities 1:N relationship.

Not sure how the mappings got there. Maybe due to a migration like Arun stated above.